# practical limit for the number of databases in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Can anyone say are if there is any practical limit for the number of databases in mongodb? I've started to have serious problems when I passed 120 databases. Simple things like :

```
> show dbs
Mon Feb 10 16:35:32 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Mon Feb 10 16:35:32 query failed : admin.$cmd { listDatabases: 1.0 } to: 127.0.0.1:27017
Mon Feb 10 16:35:32 Error: error doing query: failed src/mongo/shell/collection.js:155
Mon Feb 10 16:35:32 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017
Mon Feb 10 16:35:32 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017
>
Mon Feb 10 16:36:01 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017
Mon Feb 10 16:36:01 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 failed couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017
>
Mon Feb 10 16:37:01 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017
Mon Feb 10 16:37:01 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 ok
```

and

```
> getMemInfo()
{ "virtual" : 32, "resident" : 7 }
Mon Feb 10 16:39:00 DBClientCursor::init call() failed
Mon Feb 10 16:39:00 query failed : admin.$cmd { replSetGetStatus: 1.0, forShell: 1.0 } to: 127.0.0.1:27017
> shell
Mon Feb 10 16:39:38 ReferenceError: shell is not defined (shell):1
Mon Feb 10 16:39:38 trying reconnect to 127.0.0.1:27017
Mon Feb 10 16:39:38 reconnect 127.0.0.1:27017 ok
```

Yet the log file stayed enigmatic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of mongodb are you running on what host?
Here is a test on CenOS 6.5, mongodb 2.2 x86_64 direct from EPEL

Here is a sample python script that creates 1000 databases

```
from pymongo import MongoClient  

mc = MongoClient()
for i in range(5000):
    print i
    mc['db%s'%(i)].test.insert({"test":True})
```

output:

```
...snip...
506
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "overload_mongo.py", line 6, in <module>
    mc['db%s'%(i)].test.insert({"test":True})
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/collection.py", line 357, in insert
    continue_on_error, self.__uuid_subtype), safe)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pymongo/mongo_client.py", line 929, in _send_message
    raise AutoReconnect(str(e))
pymongo.errors.AutoReconnect: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

There it is, looking at the log

```
ERROR: Uncaught std::exception: boost::filesystem::basic_directory_iterator constructor: Too many open files: "/index/bauman/db/_tmp/esort.1392056635.506/", terminating
```

The good ole too many open files problem

If you are on a enterprise linux platform, you can drop this file into /etc/security/limits.d/mongodb.conf and start a new session

```
mongodb        hard    nofile          99999
mongodb        soft    nofile          99999
mongodb        hard    nproc          99999
mongodb        soft    nproc          99999
```

I dont know how to achieve a similar result on windows.

The 'problem' lies in that MongoDB wants to memory map every single database file, so you need your hostOS to allow it to do so.

Same code as above

```
python overload_mongo.py
```

Output

```
...snip...
995
996 
997
998
999
```

All better